# Is it possible to record video using front camera while calling in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, android-videoview

I'm developing one Android application which would record video during calling when dialing some emergency numbers. Some of my android developer friends told it is not possible. Please help me if there is any way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your app cannot know if some special number has been dialed. We can send a CALL Intent with some special number, and the Dialer system app will allow the end-user place the call. Or edit the number and place the call. It is also possible to write a broadcast handler that can be invoked when the end-user or some other app requested a call to some special number. But your app cannot perform the call itself.

If your app runs with superuser permissions (e.g. if the device is rooted), or if you replace the system Dial app with your custom one, then you certainly can control the camera while in call.

Also, if you forward the call over Internet, you can do what you want.

Finally, please note that even if you record the video during the phone call, you may not be able to live stream this video over the cellular network (some LTE networks do not turn off mobile data channel while in phone call).